# flexbox: break long text until sibling fits in container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flex children. I don't know the size of those children, but I want the `.right` (which contains unknown, but finite number of e.g. status icons) to not break, and fit on line, while `.left` child (which contains label of potentially too-long text) to break so that the `.right` child fits.

In the snippet, the `.left` should break the text so that the `.right` fits. Neither of the two children should overflow the `.container`.

I'm able to accomplish this by using `word-break: break-word` on `.left`, but that's non-standard. I can also use `word-break: break-all`, but that doesn't try to wrap the word on next line (as `word-wrap` does), first, which is undesirable. `word-wrap: break-word` doesn't do anything.

As stated, I cannot use `width: calc( 100% - <right-width> )` on `.left`, because I don't know width of `.right` child.

note: the children's `height: 20px` is just to see the parent container. It's not part of the requirement.

Bonus: in the example the width of `.container` is known, but it may potentially not be known, either (i.e. it may inherit it in some way).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: pink; 
}

.left {
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1);
  height: 20px;
  
  // word-break: break-word; // works in WebKit, but non-standard
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.right {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxox</div>
  <div class="right">rarararara</div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/g6gyf2cq/4/

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the difference is for you between using `word-break: break-all` and `word-break: break-word`. Both seem to have the desired effect for me. Also, I fail to see why it being non-standard is a concern, considering it actually has **better** support than flexbox itself...

Comment: @Michael_B I want the `.left` text to wrap instead of ellipsis.
@ObsidianAge `word-break: break-word` is [not implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) **at all** in FF and Edge, and `word-break: break-all` has minor, but significant (and undesirable) different behavior ([see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break))

Comment: Yup, I understand. It was an option I put out there for a potential simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the `min-width: 0` on `left` ensures the element doesn't `auto`-resize to the parent flex container, and wraps as needed. It can be substituted with `overflow: hidden`, which has [same effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/927631).

  If left to `auto` (default `min-width` flex value), it would overflow the container if it got too big. (thanks @Michael_B)
- `flex: 1` (shorthand for `flex: 1 0 0`, or `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 0`) ensures the `left` grows and pushes the `right` element to the right (thanks @LGSon)
- `right` has initial flex values (`flex: 0 1 auto`) which ensures it doesn't word-break and doesn't grow above its content size, either.

  WTBS, if it gets too big, it will also need `word-wrap: break-word; min-width: 0` same as left.

Note: removed the `20px` height which was not part of the OP requirement.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  background: pink; 
}

.left {
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.1);
  word-wrap: break-word;  
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
  <div class="right">cccccc ccccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, the min-width that make sense :) i forget about it ... as the flexbox apply a value to it .. but since @Michael_B didn't provide a solution i thought it won't be direct and easy :p

Comment: also no need flex:none ... the min-width is enogh ;)

Comment: here is for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333

Comment: If you want to make IE11 play along, it needs `word-break` ... and can be added like this to not mess with the rest of the browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/02zxppn2/

Comment: If you can use `flex: 1` on `left`, which will always push the `right` to the right side no matter content width in `left`, you can drop `word-break`, as that will work in IE11 too: https://jsfiddle.net/02zxppn2/2/

Comment: thanks... updated answer to reflect your points